# How to select database tables where they have two or more specific columns in them?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to select database tables where they have two or more specific columns in them?

The one here displays tables with CustomerName in them. To add another column to look for, it seems I might have to add another subquery within the subquery.

I am looking for a simple query where I can add x number of columns without adding complexity.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.name in (select t.name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID where c.name LIKE '%CustomerID%')
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

**UPDATE**
Would want to use the LIKE operator

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of tables that contain ALL of the specified columns, or ANY of them?

Comment: All of the columns specified

Comment: @Dudi Konfino It doesn't use Like and you didn't add anything extra above Chris' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want tables that contain ALL the column names you provide, an easy way without subqueries could be:

```
SELECT  t.name AS table_name,
        SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS schema_name
FROM    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE    c.name IN('COL1', 'COL2') -- Column names in here
GROUP BY t.name, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) = 2 -- Match the count of columns in the IN criteria
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id), t.name;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it by using two columns I know exist in a table and the query returned nothing. Also I prefer to be using the LIKE operator because sometimes I am not sure of column names or because there's inconsistencies in column names, eg: custid and customerid

Comment: Works for me, try the following script: https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/5c8f7079dc0b2253f1047bff628f5acc

Comment: To use LIKE operator you'll need to use nested subqueries due to the fuzzy matching potentially returning multiple column names per predicate.